# What is it called in .NET when a variable of a type is declared, but isn't actually instantiated?

Tags: .net, object, declaration, instantiation

such as:

`int i;`

or

`public delegate void MyAwesomeDelegate(int i);`

We have the word *instantiate* to mean we actually created an object. But what about when we have just declared variable of a type and it's just null?

Comment: emmm you already answered it in your question. it's called 'declaring a variable'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared a variable of type `X`, but that variable doesn't yet refer to an instantiated object.

What *does* it refer to? Depends on the type. [All reference types default to `null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Value types default to 0, false, or the like ([complete table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)).

Comment: It refers to the default for its type. All reference types default to `null`. Most numeric value types default to `0`. See edit.

Comment: @Michael: Is that default (for a reference type, i.e. null) a pending or already allocated storage location or...?

Comment: @Richard: nulls are special. They aren't any specific or particular memory location. Memory for reference types isn't allocated until the type's constructor is called.

Comment: ok. I will have to find out more about this later. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: An 'undeclared' variable wouldn't exist; as you said "you have *declared* a variable of type X'

Answer (score 2):

It is called an uninitialized variable.